# Dax Measures Filter by Month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like your assistance of a dax measure where I need to condition the filtering count of status. The problem here is it only filtered the latest date and when I filter the previous month it shows (Blank). I also don't want to sum the count if all months are selected. Here's my current measure.

```
OnTarget =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        'fact_objectives',
        'fact_objectives'[MeasureStatus] = "On Target"
            && YEAR ( 'fact_objectives'[Date] ) = YEAR ( TODAY () )
            && MONTH ( 'fact_objectives'[Date] ) = MONTH ( TODAY () )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you please share some input and expected output ?